# Ionic native calendar TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I've just installed the ionic native calendar plugin for phone gap, based on the instructions here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/calendar/

When I call anything like hasWritePermission() I get the following error:

```
index.js:685 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:685
    at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/calendar/index.js (index.js:888)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/modals/event-detail-modal/event-detail-modal.component.ts (main.js:2401)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
```

I'm using ionic 4 and angular 7, I'm wondering if this is down to unsupported dependencies? If it is, is there a more up to date plugin I can use, or am I doing something wrong here?

CODE: (addToCalendar method at the bottom)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ModalController, NavParams} from "@ionic/angular";
import {ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
import {Calendar} from "@ionic-native/calendar";


interface EventsInterface {
  title: string;
  startTime: Date;
  endTime: Date;
  ID: number;
  categoriesString: string;
  description: string;
  recurring: boolean;
  recurFrequency: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-detail-modal',
  templateUrl: './event-detail-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-detail-modal.component.scss'],
})
export class EventDetailModalComponent implements OnInit {


  /**
   *
   */
  public event: EventsInterface = null;

  /**
   *
   * @param modalController
   * @param navParams
   */
  constructor(private calendar: Calendar,private modalController: ModalController, private navParams: NavParams) { }

  /**
   *
   * @param route
   */
  ngOnInit() {

    // get the event
    this.event = <EventsInterface>this.navParams.get('event');

    console.log(this.event);
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  dismiss(){
    return this.modalController.dismiss({
      'dismissed':true
    });
  }

  addToCalendar(event: EventsInterface){

    this.calendar.hasWritePermission().then((resp: any)=>{
      console.log(resp)
    }).catch((resp: any) =>{
      console.log(resp);
    });
  }

}
```

As you can see, I've done very little so far execpt install the plugins and setup a simple promise catch...

**EDIT**
 p
It appears to be related to the wrong versions of some libraries, when installing with nom it warns:

```
npm WARN @ionic-native/calendar@4.20.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.11.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/calendar@4.20.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

The problem with this is the rest of the app is using ionic native 5.0.0 and rxjs 6.5.1 and for some reason the calendar component won't work with these newer versions?

Here is the package file:

```
{
  "name": "V3",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/calendar": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-calendar": "^5.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ion4-calendar": "^3.0.4-beta.17",
    "ionic2-calendar": "^0.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-calendar": {
        "CALENDAR_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```